# How to make a url-link from a button in Quasar version ^0.14

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In Quasar version 0.13 the way to do it was:

```
    <router-link v-bind:to="'/myurladdress'" tag='button' class='primary'>Link-name</router-link>
```

In the docs of of Quasar version 0.14.2 I merely find that you write a function on the button [click](http://quasar-framework.org/components/button.html#Vue-Events) event..?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, found an example in the quasar template:

```
    <q-btn
        @click="$router.replace('/myurladdress')"
        icon-right="home"
    >
        Go home
    </q-btn>
```

Comment: I'm confused.. i thought we needed to do v-goback directive